# Query timings in prometheus with datasource-micrometer

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer

I'm trying to publish query timing to prometheus with datasource-micrometer.

I've configured spring boot started as defined in [docs](https://jdbc-observations.github.io/datasource-micrometer/docs/current-snapshot/docs/html/#getting-started)

I see the trace and timings of queries in logs

```
2023-01-09T10:09:29.929Z  INFO [user-service,63bbe7d9a54810ffb94948d2a5724064,e35aae4db80e8647] 98235 --- [ntContainer#1-4] n.t.d.l.l.SLF4JQueryLoggingListener      : 
Name:mysql, Connection:185, Time:1, Success:True
Type:Prepared, Batch:False, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:0
Query:["select * from user where name=?;"]
Params:[(admin)]
```

And I can see generic metrics in prometheus
`jdbc_query_seconds_max{error="none",} 113.698347232`

How can I see metrics per query?

What I want is

```
jdbc_query_seconds_max{error="none",query="select * from user where name=?;"} 113.698347232
jdbc_query_seconds_max{error="none",query="select * from user where id=?;"} 113.698347232
```

Update:

I'm using spring-boot autoconfiguration so there is nothing else other than maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.ttddyy.observation</groupId>
    <artifactId>datasource-micrometer-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You would need to add a custom tag to the metrics, but I'm not sure you really want to (or should) use the query as the tag

Comment: Could you post your configuration instead of referencing what you think you have done (you might but there could be an error in your config).

Comment: @M.Deinum I want to include query in the metrics to create a dashboard similar to what spring-data provides with `spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a slippery slope since the query can be high cardinality but you can either:

- Create an `ObservationFilter` and attach what you need, you should be able to find it in the current tags or in the `Observation.Context`, see the [docs](https://jdbc-observations.github.io/datasource-micrometer/docs/current-snapshot/docs/html/#how-to-modify-the-query-in-span). What you need to do is attaching a `lowCardinalityKeyValue` to the `Observation`.
- You can override the `ObservationConvention` that is used by default and decide what tags (key-values) you want to attach.